# ag-grid: rowModelType serverSide pagination reset on sort

Tags: ag-grid

So I got the `rowModelType="serverSide"` and I use pagination. Everything works fine except for the pagination behavior upon sorting: whenever the user hits sorting, ag-grid executes `getRows(params)` with `params.request.startRow == 0` essentially resetting the pagination to the first page.
Q: how do I avoid this behavior? `getRows()` should get called of course, but with the current page (startRow)

Comment: That's the functionality. The records will be rearranged when you change the sorting. So it would anyways mean nothing if we stay on the same page. Any specific reason you would like to stay on the same page?

Comment: It's not consistent functionality. If you use clientside row model, the pagination doesn't reset upon sorting. The reason I need this is my client expects it bc of UX, specifically when the user is on the last page and uses sorting to see last/first block of results (of course, you could jump to the first page and achieve the same, but it would be an extra step). Anyway, I don't see any reason why there can't be a flag for that.

Answer (score 0):

As of v28 this behaviour is now supported and becomes consistent with the Client Side Row Model.

See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PoY2JiwQUE68f1Q1?open=main.ts) to see how the page is preserved and the `startRow` in the request following sort will still be set based on the page you are currently on.